# When running Qunit tests using ReSharper it cannot resolve namespace

Tags: jquery, resharper, qunit

This is my QUnit test:

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/global.js" />
    module("Global.js");

    test("Test getParameterFromQueryStringByName", function () {
        expect(1);
        equals("exist", jwd.global.getParameterFromQueryStringByName("xyz.com/web?querystring1=exist", "querystring1"), "Search Valid name from one parameter");
    });
```

Here `jwd.global` is a namespace defined in another javascript file called `global.js`. When I run the test from the browser by hitting some URL it works fine, but when I run the same test using ReSharper it gives me the error `jwd is not defined - { "fileName": "http://localhost:49824/Tests.js", "lineNumber": 8 }`.

How can I make sure that while running the qunit tests using ReSharper, it can find the `jwd` namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, in `global.js` I declared `jwd.global` not `jwd`. I had declared `jwd` in some other js file. After including that other js file the test runs fine.